# Intercepting HttpRequest and log contents to a database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, middleware

I would like to intercept all Httprequest and log the contents to a database table. I am using EF core, swagger and c# in vs. I would also like to add a background worker that deletes this requests every seven days.

I have tried using RequestDelegate but I am not able to save the information to a database

Comment: What exactly do you want to log? What framework are you using? Are you using .NET Framework? .NET Core? .NET 5, 6, 7? What code have you tried? Why didn't it work? etc. etc.

Comment: We need some more information. Which framework are you using? Are you using ASP.NET Core? If so, middleware is your best bet. Which data would you like to log? The IP? The time?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using .NET Core 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I was looking for. I used a middleware.

```
using Issue2.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Issue2.Middleware
{
    // You may need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions package into your project
    public class Middleware1
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public Middleware1(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, AppDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            var status = httpContext.Response.StatusCode;
            var url = httpContext.Request.Host.ToString();
            var method = httpContext.Request.Method.ToString();
            appDbContext.requestMessages.Add(new RequestMessage { Received = DateTime.Now, Method = method, Url = url, Status = status });
            appDbContext.SaveChanges();
            return _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class Middleware1Extensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMiddleware1(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<Middleware1>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit too broad to fit this forum, but here's an example of the first part at least - a request logger that saves uri and body of a request to a database table;

```
public class RequestMessageLogger : IRequestMessageLogger
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public RequestMessageLogger(MyDbContext dbContext, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void LogRequest()
    {
        string bodyAsString = null;
        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Body.CanSeek)
        {
            RewindStream();

            using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true);
            bodyAsString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            RewindStream();
        }
            
        var uri = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();

        _dbContext.RequestMessages.Add(new RequestMessage { Message = bodyAsString, Received = DateTime.Now, Uri = uri });

        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void RewindStream() => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
}
```

Just inject it in to your controller and use it like so;

```
[HttpGet("hello")]
public ActionResult Hello()
{
    _requestMessageLogger.LogRequest();
    return Ok();
}
```